# How to enable/Disbale iTunes files sharing from with in the iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes

I have a requirement to enable/disable **file sharing** from with in the App. My **iPhone** app which shares all the data in the documents to let user to take a **backup** of the data from **iTunes** so that he can **restore** it later. I know that i can achieve this by changing the app **info.plist to enable/disable** the **iTunes file sharing**, but as i have to disable/enable it from within the App i.e from App settings screen.

Please suggest me that how to achieve this functionality.

Thanks for you answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to do it through code on run time. There is a trick to do it but it's can be only good if you don't have much data to to share. Enable file sharing in plist. Then put all files in a folder name like "Share" then put a switch in UI, when user turn off switch then rename this folder like this ".Share" then it will be hidden and no longer available for sharing.

Note : It's a trick not a good way but it works when you needed it hardly.

Answer (score 2):

Cheers, sorry for the length of time between ask and answer.

You're looking for the UIFileSharingEnabled key in the info plist of your app.

The link for their developer pages no longer shows this information, or maybe I just can't find it, but, add this to your plist file

```
<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
<true/>
```

cheers

Comment: As seen above, this is a key value pair and does NOT indicate a container relationship.